# PHP sockets: sending successful, but unable to retrieve response

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, mirth

I'm implementing a web service which sends [HL7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_Level_7) messages through the [MLLP](https://www.hl7.org/documentcenter/public/wg/inm/mllp_transport_specification.PDF) protocol to several service providers. In practice, this should be as simple as sending a valid string surrounded by `<VT>` and `<FS><CR>`. So, something like (this is pseudocode):

```
$socket = create_socket($destIp, $destPort);
$socket->send("\013".$hl7Message."\034\015");
$response = $socket->read();
```

I've been using [this library](https://github.com/senaranya/HL7) for that (the sending code is on [this file](https://github.com/senaranya/HL7/blob/master/src/HL7/Connection.php) in particular), which uses `socket_create()`, `socket_write()` and `socket_read()`. It works perfectly, except for one service provider, where it times out waiting for data. Using tcpdump I can see that the data is successfully sent, a packet with the response is received, but PHP fails to retrieve the response data through `socket_read()`.

Just to be sure, I tried reimplementing it with stream sockets, so I used the functions `stream_socket_client()`, `stream_socket_sendto()` and `stream_socket_recvfrom()` on an otherwise mostly identical function. The result is mostly the same.

[Mirth](https://github.com/nextgenhealthcare/connect), a Java-based platform for handling HL7 messages, doesn't have any trouble sending to this provider. I don't have any issues sending messages to Mirth, either. The only issue is my receiving their responses when sending directly.

Considering they're a multinational company and I'm a lowly freelance programmer, I'd like to know what else I can do to find out what's the issue and, if possible, how to solve it. Any hints on how to debug this, or alternative ways of implementing this (without relying on middlemen – I know I could send the messages to Mirth and have it send them to the service provider, but it's an extra point of failure I'd like to avoid) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Years ago I have implemented a similar system on HL7 thru PHP (actually the system was for transmission of radiology data) , I remember that the following library can help: [HL7_PHP](https://github.com/senaranya/HL7). Please pay particular attention to the section on `ACK message returned from a remote HL7 listener`

Comment: That's precisely the library I've been using. It is indeed a great help when working with HL7 in PHP, but I get a timeout on the first line of code of the section you mentioned: `$ack = (new Connection($ip, $port))->send($message);`. Using tcpdump was actually a troubleshooting suggestion by the library's author.

Comment: I used tcpdump to capture incoming traffic, and a packet with their response is indeed being received on my end. It's just that the PHP socket isn't reading that data – that I know has been received – and I don't know why. Also, if I send a message through Mirth to the same IP and port, the response is properly received.

Comment: What **exactly** is the code that is not correctly reading in the data you know was sent.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk It's in [this file](https://github.com/senaranya/HL7/blob/master/src/HL7/Connection.php) (Github link). It's a pretty simple and self-explanatory implementation, with the socket being created on `setSocket()` and the data being sent, and the response read, on `send()`. I have, as you might expect, set `$noWait` to false.